# How do I use ArgumentCaptor after ArgumentMatcher?

Tags: java, mockito, matcher

I have some common interface to mock:

```
public interface RequestHandler {
  public Object handle(Object o);
}
```

And this mocked interface should handle different requests in single test.

```
when(mock.handle(isA(ARequest.class))).thenReturn(new AResponse());
when(mock.handle(isA(BRequest.class))).thenReturn(new BResponse());
```

But I want to capture passed instance of `BRequest` to check all its params. Is it possible somehow?

For now I see only one solution: build a monstrous extension of `ArgumentMatcher`. However, I don't like this, because I will not see `AssertionError` messages.

Answer (score 3):

Remember: Though matchers are for both stubs and verifications, ArgumentCaptor is for verifications only. That makes it simple:

```
ArgumentCaptor<BRequest> bCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.for(BRequest.class);
when(mock.handle(isA(BRequest.class))).thenReturn(new BResponse());

systemUnderTest.handle(createBRequest());

verify(mock).handle(bCaptor.capture());
BRequest bRequest = bCaptor.getValue();
// your assertions here
```

Note, however, that that also means you can't use ArgumentCaptor to select the response. That's where partial mocks or Answers come in:

```
when(mock.handle(any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
  @Override public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    Object argument = invocation.getArguments()[0];
    // your assertions here, and you can return your desired value
  }
});
```

---

Should you choose an ArgumentMatcher, it likely won't be all that monstrous, especially if you skip a factory method and let Mockito's de-camel-casing be your description:

```
public static class IsAnAppropriateBRequest extends ArgumentMatcher<Object> {
  @Override public boolean matches(Object object) {
    if !(object instanceof BRequest) {
      return false;
    }
    BRequest bRequest = (BRequest) object;
    // your assertions here
  }
}

when(mock.handle(argThat(new IsAnAppropriateBRequest())))
    .thenReturn(new BResponse());
```

Comment: This is not the way I wanted it to be, but thanks anyway. Maybe I'll use ArgumentMatcher with assertions, smth like this:
argThat(bRequest().withLength(123).withComment("qwe123"))

Comment: Please consider updating your question, if you want to make it clear what degree of matching you're looking for and why supplied answers are insufficient. If making a flexible matcher, you might also favor the [BaseMatcher in Hamcrest 1.3](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.html), which has a handy `describeMismatch` method that gives you the reporting granularity you mentioned. A Builder-pattern Matcher is clever, but be careful: toolkits like Mockito can depend on the Hamcrest-documented assumption that Matchers are immutable and idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, the fact that this method can take so many different types of parameters is a code smell. A method that returns many different kinds of responses for different input parameters is a clear violation of this. See [One Thing: Extract till you Drop.](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop)

> For years authors and consultants (like me) have been telling us that functions should do one thing. They should do it well. They should do it only.

That said, you can pass a [Partial Mock](http://blog.javabien.net/2009/06/21/mockitos-partial-mocks-testing-real-objects-just-got-easier/) into your class. See: [Real Partial Mocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16)

Example:

```
BRequest bSpy = spy(new BRequest());
when(mock.handle(bSpy))).thenReturn(new BResponse());
verify(bSpy, times(2)).someMethod();
```

`bSpy` won't return null, because it's a **real instance** of a `BRequest`, but because it's a spy, it allows you to call things like verify on it.

Comment: This is not unit test for atomic code block, its more like function test for stateless application/unit, that was mocked on transport layer from other system units. So it is very abstract "handler" for many messages. It can be wrapped to make it more concrete, but I expected not to add "more wrappers for wrappers". If its not posted yet, then its not possible at the time. There are several workarounds: 1) Mockito.spy 2) wrapper with different methods 3) assertions inside ArgumentMatcher

Comment: @Dmitry `Mockito.spy` is what I'm suggesting here.

Comment: Its worth to mension that using partial mocks is usally considered code smell